# TcpClient не принимает данные

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Есть код принятия данных с `TcpClient`. Он работает в таске, имитирующем клиент, но не в классе клиента. Исключений не возникает. Оно не зависает, но зацикливается, так как ждёт сигнала о наличии данных для получения. А его нет.

Чтобы понять, что код должен делать, надо закомментировать блок "Не происходит получение" и раскомментировать блок "Происходит получение".

```
namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13888);
                listener.Start();
                TcpConnection client = new TcpConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
                Console.WriteLine("Server: new connection!");
                client.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(client.client.GetStream());

                // Происходит получение
                //while (client.client.Available == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
                //Console.WriteLine($"Server (available: {client.client.Available}): " +
                //    $"has been received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(client.client.Available))}");

                // Не происходит получение
                while (client.GetReceivedCount() == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine($"Server (available: {client.GetReceivedCount()}): " +
                    $"has been received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.GetReceived().ToArray())}");
            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                TcpConnection connection = new TcpConnection();
                connection.SetEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 13888);
                connection.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
                connection.Connect();
                if (connection.IsActive())
                {
                    connection.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Text"));
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class TcpConnection
    {
        public readonly TcpClient client;
        private BinaryReader reader;
        private BinaryWriter writer;

        private string ip;
        private int port;

        private Task receiveTask;

        private readonly List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();

        public ReceivingState ReceivingState
        {
            get
            {
                lock (receiveStateObject)
                {
                    return receivingState;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock (receiveStateObject)
                {
                    receivingState = value;
                }
            }
        }
        private ReceivingState receivingState = ReceivingState.Both;
        private readonly object receiveStateObject = new object();

        public event ReceiveData OnReceiveData;

        public TcpConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            this.client = client;
            if (IsActive())
            {
                reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
                writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
            }
        }
        public TcpConnection()
            : this(new TcpClient())
        { }

        public bool IsActive()
        {
            try
            {
                client.GetStream().Write(new byte[0]);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void SetEndPoint(string ip, int port)
        {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public void Connect()
        {
            client.Connect(ip, port);
            reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
            writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
            receiveTask= Task.Run(() => BeginReceive());
        }

        public void Disconnect()
        {
            client.Close();
            reader.Close();
            writer.Close();
            receiveTask.Dispose();
        }

        public void Send(byte[] message)
        {
            if (IsActive())
            {
                writer.Write(message);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }

        private void BeginReceive()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (IsActive() && client.Available > 0)
                    {
                        byte[] temp;

                        // Не происходит получение
                        temp = reader.ReadBytes(client.Available);

                        lock (receiveStateObject)
                        {
                            if (ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Method || ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Both)
                                lock (receivedBytes)
                                {
                                    receivedBytes.AddRange(temp);
                                }
                            if (ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Event || ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Both)
                                OnReceiveData?.Invoke(temp.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<byte> GetReceived()
        {
            lock (receivedBytes)
            {
                foreach (var item in receivedBytes)
                    yield return item;
                receivedBytes.Clear();
            }
        }
        public int GetReceivedCount()
        {
            lock (receivedBytes)
            {
                return receivedBytes.Count;
            }
        }
    }
    public enum ReceivingState : byte
    {
        Method,
        Event,
        Both
    }
    public delegate void ReceiveData(byte[] message);
}
```

Comment: Что такое класс клиента? Здесь много всяких ошибок в коде. Уберите закоментированный код, он мешает читать незакоментированный, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Класс клиента - это TcpConnection, оборачивающий TcpClient.
Каких ошибок много в коде?
Как отредактировать вопрос? Точнее, что вам в нём не нравится?

Comment: Вы угараете надо мной? Текст ошибки и/или текущее поведение напишите вменяемо, а не вот эти приколы. Ничего же непонятно. Что значит не принимаются? Из кдасса не принимвются, а из чего тогда принимаются? Как отлаживали? Какие исключения возникают? Оно зависает? На какой строчке? При вызове из первой запущенной таски или из второй? Что вообще делает ваш код, или должен делать, или догадаться надо? Я пишу вам про оформление вопроса не потому что "так надо", а потому что непонятно ничего.

Comment: Вы код смотрели? По-моему там в комментариях написано достаточно. А если нет - отвечу на любой конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Это означает, что TcpClient не знает о поступивших данных.
Уже поправил в вопросе.
Многочисленным нажатием на F10 и F11 и использованием точек останова :)
Никаких.
Тут интереснее. И да, и нет. Оно не зависает, но зацикливается, так как ждёт сигнала о наличии данных для получения. А его нет.
Не понял.
Чтобы понять, что код должен делать, надо закомментировать блок "Не работает" и раскомментировать блок "Работает".

Да что ж такое, почему разделение строк слетает...

Comment: В Markdown перенос строки - это 2 пробела в конце предыдущей строки, либо разбивка по параграфам - пустая строка между блоками текста. Чуть позже гляну код.

Comment: Спасибо. Чуть-чуть не успел сам отредактировать :)

Comment: @ProMix не вижу у вас вызова Connect. Откуда возьмётся сигнал о получении данных?

Comment: @ProMix кстати, перестаньте использовать ожидание в цикле со Sleep

Comment: Вторая таска, четвёртая строчка.
Я бы с радостью, но на что while заменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну получение в классе не происходит, потому что вы не запускаете этот процесс.

```cs
public TcpConnection(TcpClient client)
{
    this.client = client;
    if (IsActive())
    {
        reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
        writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
        receiveTask = Task.Run(() => BeginReceive());
    }
}
```

---

Пока разбирал ваш код, немного переписал, может что-то отсюда пригодится. Если кратко, то крутить `Sleep` в цикле - не хорошо, лучше все-таки использовать блокировку потока на основе поведения `NetworkStream`, а еще лучше - асинхронное ожидание (см. [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async)).

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13888);
            listener.Start();
            TcpConnection client = new TcpConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient());
            client.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
            Console.WriteLine("Server: new connection!");

            while (client.GetReceivedCount() == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine($"Server (available: {client.GetReceivedCount()}): " +
                $"has been received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.GetReceived().ToArray())}");
        });
        Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            TcpConnection connection = new TcpConnection();
            connection.SetEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 13888);
            connection.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
            connection.Connect();
            if (connection.IsActive)
            {
                connection.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Text"));
            }
            connection.Disconnect();
        });
        await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class TcpConnection
{
    private readonly TcpClient client;
    private NetworkStream stream;

    private string ip;
    private int port;

    private Task receiveTask;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<byte> receivedBytes = new ConcurrentQueue<byte>();
    private CancellationTokenSource cts;

    public ReceivingState ReceivingState
    {
        get
        {
            lock (receiveStateObject)
            {
                return receivingState;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            lock (receiveStateObject)
            {
                receivingState = value;
            }
        }
    }
    private ReceivingState receivingState = ReceivingState.Both;
    private readonly object receiveStateObject = new object();

    public event ReceiveData OnReceiveData;

    public TcpConnection(TcpClient client)
    {
        this.client = client;
        if (client.Connected)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            stream = client.GetStream();
            receiveTask = BeginReceive();
        }
    }
    public TcpConnection()
        : this(new TcpClient())
    { }

    public bool IsActive => client.Connected;

    public void SetEndPoint(string ip, int port)
    {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
        cts?.Dispose();
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        client.Connect(ip, port);
        stream = client.GetStream();
        receiveTask = BeginReceive();
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        cts?.Cancel();
        receiveTask.Wait();
        cts?.Dispose();
        cts = null;
        client.Close();
    }

    public void Send(byte[] message)
    {
        if (IsActive)
        {
            stream.Write(message);
        }
    }

    private async Task BeginReceive()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesReceived = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, cts.Token);

                lock (receiveStateObject)
                {
                    if (ReceivingState.HasFlag(ReceivingState.Method))
                        for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived; i++)
                            receivedBytes.Enqueue(buffer[i]);

                    if (ReceivingState.HasFlag(ReceivingState.Event))
                        OnReceiveData?.Invoke(buffer[0..bytesReceived]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<byte> GetReceived()
    {
        lock (receiveStateObject)
        {
            while (receivedBytes.TryDequeue(out byte b))
                yield return b;
        }
    }
    public int GetReceivedCount()
    {
        lock (receiveStateObject)
        {
            return receivedBytes.Count;
        }
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum ReceivingState : byte
{
    Method = 1,
    Event = 2,
    Both = Method | Event
}

public delegate void ReceiveData(byte[] message);
```

Comment: Тупая ошибка, отслеживание которой было затруднено многопоточность.Спасибо!
А ожидал я, по сути, асинхронно - через выделенную таску.
Пойду проверять :)