# TcpClient снова не принимает данные

Tags: c#, tcpclient

Есть класс, принимающий данные через `TcpClient` (`TcpConnection`). Полностью работает. Есть его наследник - `RsaDecorator`. Его метод `Connect()` (строка 240) должен передавать свой публичный ключ и получать чужой в ответ. Для этого есть методы `SendKey()` и `ReceiveKey()`. Они почему-то не работают (блок "Не работает") :). Точнее, происходит вход в бесконечный цикл ожидания ответа. Таска с получением ответа запущена с обоих сторон, проверял :). Для проверки в метод добавил обмен сообщениями - всё работает (блок "Работает"). Не ясно, в чём проблема.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Server thread";
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13888);
                listener.Start();
                TcpConnection client = new RsaDecorator(new TcpConnection(listener.AcceptTcpClient()));
                Console.WriteLine("Server: new connection!");
                client.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
                client.Connect();
                while (client.GetReceivedCount() == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
                Console.WriteLine($"Server (available: {client.GetReceivedCount()}): " +
                    $"has been received message: {Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.GetReceived().ToArray())}");
            });
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Client thread";
                TcpConnection connection = new RsaDecorator(new TcpConnection());
                connection.SetEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 13888);
                connection.ReceivingState = ReceivingState.Method;
                connection.Connect();
                if (connection.IsActive())
                {
                    connection.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Text"));
                }
            });
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class TcpConnection
    {
        private readonly TcpClient client;
        private BinaryReader reader;
        private BinaryWriter writer;
        private NetworkStream stream;

        private string ip;
        private int port;

        private Task receiveTask;

        private readonly List<byte> receivedBytes = new List<byte>();

        public virtual ReceivingState ReceivingState
        {
            get
            {
                lock (receiveStateObject)
                {
                    return receivingState;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                lock (receiveStateObject)
                {
                    receivingState = value;
                }
            }
        }
        private ReceivingState receivingState = ReceivingState.Both;
        private object receiveStateObject = new object();

        public virtual event ReceiveData OnReceiveData;

        public TcpConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            this.client = client;
            if (IsActive())
            {
                reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
                writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
                receiveTask = Task.Run(() => BeginReceive());
            }
        }
        public TcpConnection()
            : this(new TcpClient())
        { }

        public virtual bool IsActive()
        {
            try
            {
                client.GetStream().Write(new byte[0]);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public virtual void SetEndPoint(string ip, int port)
        {
            this.ip = ip;
            this.port = port;
        }

        public virtual void Connect()
        {
            if (ip != null && port != 0)
            {
                client.Connect(ip, port);
                reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());
                writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());
                stream = client.GetStream();
                receiveTask = Task.Run(() => BeginReceive());
            }
        }

        public virtual void Disconnect()
        {
            client.Close();
            reader.Close();
            writer.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }

        public virtual void Send(byte[] message)
        {
            if (IsActive())
            {
                writer.Write(message);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }

        private void BeginReceive()
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Receive thread";
            while (true)
            {
                if (IsActive() && client.Available != 0)
                {
                    byte[] temp = reader.ReadBytes(client.Available);

                    lock (receiveStateObject)
                    {
                        if (ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Method || ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Both)
                            lock (receivedBytes)
                            {
                                receivedBytes.AddRange(temp);
                            }
                        if (ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Event || ReceivingState == ReceivingState.Both)
                            lock (receivedBytes)
                            {
                                OnReceiveData?.Invoke(temp.ToArray());
                            }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<byte> GetReceived()
        {
            lock (receivedBytes)
            {
                foreach (var item in receivedBytes)
                    yield return item;
                receivedBytes.Clear();
            }
        }

        public virtual int GetReceivedCount()
        {
            lock (receivedBytes)
            {
                return receivedBytes.Count;
            }
        }
    }

    public class RsaDecorator:TcpConnection
    {
        private TcpConnection innerConnection;

        private RSAParameters publicKey;
        private RSAParameters privateKey;

        private readonly KeyGen keyGen = new KeyGen();

        public override ReceivingState ReceivingState
        {
            get => innerConnection.ReceivingState;
            set => innerConnection.ReceivingState = value;
        }
        public override event ReceiveData OnReceiveData;

        private bool connectionCompleted = false;

        public RsaDecorator(TcpConnection connection)
        {
            innerConnection = connection;
            innerConnection.OnReceiveData += (byte[] message) =>
            {
                OnReceiveData?.Invoke(Decrypt(message));
            };
        }

        private void SendKey(RSAParameters key)
        {
            RsaSerializable serializableKey = new RsaSerializable(key);
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, serializableKey);
            Console.WriteLine($"Length of stream: {stream.Length}");
            innerConnection.Send(stream.ToArray());
        }
        private RSAParameters ReceiveKey()
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            using Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            while (innerConnection.GetReceivedCount() == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
            stream.Write(innerConnection.GetReceived().ToArray());
            return ((RsaSerializable)formatter.Deserialize(stream)).GetAsRsaParameters();
        }

        public override void Connect()
        {
            if (!innerConnection.IsActive())
                innerConnection.Connect();
            privateKey = keyGen.GetRSAParameters();

            // Не работает
            SendKey(privateKey);
            publicKey = ReceiveKey();

            // Работает
            //innerConnection.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Some text"));
            //while (innerConnection.GetReceivedCount() == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);
            //Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(innerConnection.GetReceived().ToArray()));

            connectionCompleted = true;
        }

        public override void Disconnect()
        {
            connectionCompleted = false;
            innerConnection.Disconnect();
        }

        public override bool IsActive()
        {
            return connectionCompleted && innerConnection.IsActive();
        }

        public override IEnumerable<byte> GetReceived()
        {
            return Decrypt(innerConnection.GetReceived().ToArray());
        }

        public override void Send(byte[] message)
        {
            innerConnection.Send(Encrypt(message));
        }

        public override void SetEndPoint(string ip, int port)
        {
            innerConnection.SetEndPoint(ip, port);
        }

        private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] message)
        {
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
            return rsa.Encrypt(message, false);
        }

        private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] message)
        {
            using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
            return rsa.Decrypt(message, false);
        }

        public override int GetReceivedCount()
        {
            return innerConnection.GetReceivedCount();
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class RsaSerializable
        {
            public byte[] Exponent;
            public byte[] Modulus;

            public RsaSerializable(RSAParameters parameters)
            {
                Exponent = parameters.Exponent;
                Modulus = parameters.Modulus;
            }
            public RSAParameters GetAsRsaParameters()
            {
                return new RSAParameters() { Exponent = Exponent, Modulus = Modulus };
            }
        }

        private class KeyGen
        {

            internal int KeysCount { get; set; } = 2;

            private Queue<RSAParameters> Keys;

            /// <summary>
            ///  Метод, возвращающий ключ
            /// </summary>
            internal RSAParameters GetRSAParameters()
            {
                // Заполнение очереди с ключами до указанного количества +1
                for (int i = 0; i <= KeysCount - Keys.Count; i++)
                    GenerateKeyToQueue();

                // Ожидание появления ключей в очереди
                while (Keys.Count == 0) Thread.Sleep(100);

                // Извлечение результата
                lock (Keys)
                {
                    return Keys.Dequeue();
                }
            }

            internal KeyGen()
            {

                Keys = new Queue<RSAParameters>();
                GenerateKeyToQueue();

            }

            /// <summary>
            ///  Метод, генерирующий ключ и добавляющий его в очередь
            /// </summary>
            private void GenerateKeyToQueue()
            {
                // Запуск асинхронной генерации
                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // Генерация
                    using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    RSAParameters result = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

                    // Добавление в очередь
                    lock (Keys)
                    {
                        Keys.Enqueue(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    public enum ReceivingState : byte
    {
        Method,
        Event,
        Both
    }
    public delegate void ReceiveData(byte[] message);
}
```

Comment: 1) `BinaryFormatter` небезопасен: [_BinaryFormatter security guide_](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide), его нельзя использовать для данных, полученных из публичной сети. 2) `BinaryReader`/`BinaryWriter` вам не нужны, совсем, так как то, ради чего они созданы в .NET, вы не используете. 3) Про то что крутить Sleep в цикле - плохо, я уже вам говорил. Я вам [отрефакторил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1209533/373567) почти готовый класс, но вы проигнорировали решение (полностью!). Почему?

Comment: 1) Спасибо, не знал, поменяю на XmlSerializer.  
2) Согласен, кусок из старого проекта.  
3) Ну, цикл всё равно будет крутиться, не в моём коде, так в недрах системы. За класс спасибо, но я решил сначала сделать так, как я себе представлял, а потом улучшать. Плюс не сильно хотелось копаться в чужом коде :). Но наверное да, надо было начать с интеграции частей вашего класса. Чем я сейчас и займусь.

Comment: Здесь дело не столько в улучшении, сколько в стремлении понять, что и почему я в вашем коде изменил. Я не уверен, что я все сделал правильно, и что оно во всех местах лучше вашего, я просто сделал предложение, но не может же быть оно на 100% бесполезно, поэтому и удивился. По поводу крутящихся циклов - вы не правы, асинхронное ожидание при операциях ввода вывода никаких циклов не крутит, а просто ставит коллбэк в очередь аппаратуре и завершает операцию, и аппаратура фактически коллбэк вызывает. То есть используется 0 потоков для выполнения кода, код не выполняется при ожидании. Большая разница

Comment: По поводу сериализатора, используйте тогда уж `JsonSerializer`, если вы на .NET Core/.NET 5 или пакет `Newtonsoft.Json`, если на Framework. 1) Json компактнее. 2) Json проще.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: При работе с потоками забудьте про `Thread.Sleep()`, есть асинхронный `await Task.Delay()`. Я пока еще не понял, но кажется у вас deadlock. То есть одному потоку надо выполнить 2 работы одновременно, но это технически невозможно. Почитайте про дедлоки в C#, на вскидку не вспомню полезных ссылок, но тема в интернете разжевана хорошо. И вам для той задачи, что вы решаете, многопоточность не совсем подходит, так вся работа связана с I/O, а для этого лучше использовать асинхронность - `async/await`, ссылка на материал в моем прошлом ответе.

Comment: Подсказка, у `MemoryStream` есть метод `.ToArray()`. Напишите, как обновите и проверите код, а я потом посмотрю, как оно работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Как я понял, проблема была в местоположении указателя потока? Просто больше идей нет :)  
По интеграции вашего кода - сделал... но он снова не работает :) В чём причина пока не знаю, сейчас буду разбираться. Отпишусь.

Comment: Обновите код в вопросе как разберетесь. (или не разберетесь)

Comment: По поводу вашего кода - не работает. Упорно. Как я понимаю, не работает метод получения. Но только у клиента. Попытки перенести сам класс в другой проект (TestProject) не дали ничего, кроме отсутствия проблемы. Поэтому ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/ProMix0/Project-calculis-1.1

Comment: Я и не говорил, что моя реализация вашего класса поможет. Я вам предложил всего-лишь в ней разобраться и повыкидывать лишние костыли, чтобы было проще жить. Простое копирование кода конечно ни к чему не приведет, так как моя реализация - и ваша изначальная, идентичны по поведению, разве что моя слегка побыстрее в плане производительности, и меньше кушает ресурсов. А вы так рассуждаете, как-будто я вас в чем-то обманул. Обещал помочь, и не помог.

Comment: Нет, суть я понял. Но к сведению приму. Спасибо